# Regex for phone numbers, allowing mandatory 10 digits and `+`, `()`, space characters

Tags: regex

Searching a regex for phone numbers, allowing mandatory 10 digits and +, (), space characters,

I tried below code but it's not working:

```
"^[0-9]{10,10}[' '+()]$"
```

Comment: Your regex will match exactly 10 digits, followed by one of the following: single quote, space, plus, left paren, right paren.  You should review the usage of the quantifer braces and the character class brackets.

Comment: How could i make change to regex to allow multiple (space,+left parran and right paran) ?

Comment: Why do you even try forcing a format for phone numbers? Hyphen-minus is allowed in the usual phone number format too, by the way.

Comment: a google search on this reveals many regex patterns you may consider.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what patterns you are trying to match.  Is (+++) 9999 a valid phone number?  How about (212) 555-1212? But I think the regex posted by KurzedMetal is close to what you want.  Test your regex with an online tool like  http://www.regextester.com/ so that you can understand how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try   `^[ ()+]*([0-9][ ()+]*){10}$`

This will match exactly 10 digits with any number of ,`(`,`)`,`+` characters any where else in the input.

Comment: +1 Almost exactly what I was going to post. [example here](http://regexr.com?30n0m)

Comment: @Wiseguy - great minds think alike. Coincidentally, so do ours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^[0-9\ \(\)\+]{10}$`

Comment: THis restricts entire length to 10 charcters but how to allow multiple ( +, left paran, right paran and space) and limit to 10 digiits

Comment: You don't need all that masking inside the group, do you?

Comment: I obviously misunderstood the OP's question, because he didn't specify the amount of "+, (), space characters" he wanted so i supposed it was part of those 10 chars.